# Python - Groupby - Excel - como retirar a mesclagem do index

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, dataframe, group-by

Estou tentando fazer um groupby de valores de um dataframe para em seguida exportar para o excel.

Escrevi as duas linhas abaixo para realizar esse procedimento:

```
df_dados_entradas2 = pd.DataFrame(lst_entradas_temp).groupby(['CNPJ Estab', 'Código do Item', 'Cód. Participante']).sum()
df_dados_entradas2.to_excel('Base resumida.xlsx')
```

O resultado é o que está na imagem abaixo. Esse procedimento agrupa e soma a qntd e os valores 1, 2 e 3 com base nas três colunas do dataframe (CNPJ Estab, Código do Item e Cód. Participante).

[image: Imagem]

Gostaria de ajuda para exportar o dataframe para o excel sem a mesclagem dos index destacados em amarelo, de modo que atinja o resultado abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -3):

Resolvi o problema adicionando o parâmetro `as_index=False` na função `groupby`.